# Blinking fixed header in site with scrolling animation

Tags: javascript, css, dom

So I'm putting a website together which will have a few css3 animations triggered on the scroll event. About halfway through writing the scrolling animations, I'm noticing a lot of blinking on the page's header and other position:fixed elements.

Is there something I can do to minimize this blinking? (Ideally without jQuery)

Comment: I'm not seeing blinking (in chrome) but the centre lady on the Our Team bit looks terrified.

Comment: The blinking happens for me when the header scrolls over the `DemoContent1` div.. i removed it with inspect element and there was no blinking.

Comment: No blinking here (ff)

Comment: @johnnycardy No kidding. She's just a placeholder, but one of my co-workers put a bow over her when he was working on the site.

Comment: Got it figured out and answered below. Thanks for your feedback, guys.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, it looks like this issue is probably isolated to chrome and the speed at which fixed positioned elements render when CSS animations are firing off during scroll.

I wanted to see if [this little trick](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d) would hardware-accelerate elements that weren't actually the subject of a CSS animation in chrome. Turns out it did. :)

Here's the solution:

```
.topbar
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: I had a blinking header in iOS when a text input got the focus. Your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

The `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` did not fix the issue in my case for e.g. BS `navbar`. But instead I stumbled over a different solution which fixed the problem for AOS, Animate.css and also WOW.js. In my case all elements with `position: fixed` had erratic behaviour when scrolling on mobile (touch devices) through the site.

An approach I found [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/274) and [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/741) did completely solve the existing problems. Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your `body` a/o `section` elements that contain the animation.

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

or

```
section { overflow-x: hidden; } //might be a different container element
```

Finally my BS navbar is no longer affected by any animations.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in *FIREFOX*  Browser. but thing I observed once you open a debug mode, from that moment to until reload,fixed header not blink

Comment: @priyankaahire Cannot confirm this behaviour for me this issue also occurs on Chrome as well. Debug and Android.

Answer (score 1):

There will be somethingg wrong with your javascript code. I faced the same problem

for eg :

This was the code with blinking div :

```
    window.onscroll = function () {
            var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky");
            var value = sticky.offsetTop;
                if(window.pageYOffset > value){
                    sticky.classList.add("sticky");
                    console.log("sticky");
                }else{
                    sticky.classList.remove("sticky");
                    console.log("nonsticky");
                }
            }
```

The problem was that i declared variable in on scroll function

The fix :

```
        var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky");
        var value = sticky.offsetTop;

        window.onscroll = function () {
            if(window.pageYOffset > value){
                sticky.classList.add("sticky");
                console.log("sticky");
            }else{
                sticky.classList.remove("sticky");
                console.log("nonsticky");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to `> 1` instead of `> 50` or `> 25`:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    // Change the scrollTop conditions here.
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1) {
        yourTopBarInnerElement.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        yourTopBarInnerElement.style.display = "block";
    };
};
```

It works for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: sticky;` instead of `position: fixed`;

Answer (score 0):

```
**Blinking Fixed Header issue I am facing only in Firebox. Animation property not supported by Firebox?**

*In below code i am applying tranform property to all column who has freeze_vertical class*


  var fixed_vertical_elts = document.getElementsByClassName(table_class + " freeze_vertical");

for (i = 0; i < fixed_vertical_elts.length; i++) {
   fixed_vertical_elts[i].style.webkitTransform = translate_y;
   fixed_vertical_elts[i].style.transform = translate_y;
   fixed_vertical_elts[i].style.background = "#fff";
}



*but one thing I observed once you open a debug mode, from that moment to until reload,fixed header not blink.*


Thanks in adavance
```