# The header has flickering issue on scroll in chrome? what's the reason?

Tags: html, css

The code creates a fixed header on page, issue here is that header flickers on scroll, How do i avoid this flickering issue?

```
<header></header>

.header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use .header? Is not .selector used for classes? You are trying to style the header so I guess it should be header{your CSS}

Comment: just encountered this issue as well. will file a bug report to chrome devs.

Comment: This answer solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907500/1290457 Basically you add a CSS 3dtransform to the header element. (I didn't believe it would work first, but I tried and the blinking is gone).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

try adding this piece of code. it will fix the problem